# Return all matches of a regular expression in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

I have a table that contains a VARCHAR2 column called COMMANDS.

The data in this column is a bunch of difficult to read ZPL code that will be sent to a label printer, and amidst the ZPL there are several tokens in the form {TABLE.COLUMN}.

I would a like nice list of all the distinct {TABLE.COLUMN} tokens that are found in COMMANDS.  I wrote the following regex to match the token format:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(COMMANDS,'\{\w+\.\w+\}') FROM MYTABLE;
```

The regex works, but it only returns the first matched token per row.  Is there a way to return all regex matches for each row?

I'm using Oracle 11GR2.

Edit - Here is a small sample of data from a single row -- there are many such lines in each row:

```
^FO360,065^AEN,25,10^FD{CUSTOMERS.CUST_NAME}^FS
^FO360,095^AAN,15,12^FD{CUSTOMERS.CUST_ADDR1}^FS
```

So if that was the only row in table, I'd like to have returned:

```
{CUSTOMERS.CUST_NAME}
{CUSTOMERS.CUST_ADDR1}
```

Comment: What about using regexp_replace to replace everything that does *not* match the pattern with an empty string? That should leave all occurances in the result.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Agree. Would require less code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've provided sample of data saying that this is a single row but have presented it as two different rows. So this example based on your words.

```
 -- Sample of data from your question + extra row for the sake of demonstration
 -- id column is added to distinguish the rows(I assume you have one)
  with t1(id, col) as( 
    select 1, '^FO360,065^AEN,25,10^FD{CUSTOMERS1.CUST_NAME}^FS^FO360,095^AAN,15,12^FD{CUSTOMERS1.CUST_ADDR1}^FS' from dual union all
    select 2, '^FO360,065^AEN,25,10^FD{CUSTOMERS2.CUST_NAME}^FS^FO360,095^AAN,15,12^FD{CUSTOMERS2.CUST_ADDR2}^FS' from dual
  ),
  cnt(c) as(
    select level
      from (select max(regexp_count(col, '{\w+.\w+}')) as o_c
              from t1
            ) z
     connect by level <= z.o_c
  )
  select t1.id, listagg(regexp_substr(t1.col, '{\w+.\w+}', 1, cnt.c)) within group(order by t1.id) res
    from t1
   cross join cnt
   group by t1.id
```

Result:

```
    ID   RES
    ---------------------------------------------------------
     1   {CUSTOMERS1.CUST_ADDR1}{CUSTOMERS1.CUST_NAME}
     2   {CUSTOMERS2.CUST_ADDR2}{CUSTOMERS2.CUST_NAME}
```

As per @a_horse_with_no_name [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14222927/997660) to the question, really, it's much simpler to just replace everything else that doesn't match the pattern. Here is an example:

```
 with t1(col) as(
    select '^FO360,065^AEN,25,10^FD{CUSTOMERS.CUST_NAME}^FS^FO360,095^AAN,15,12^FD{CUSTOMERS.CUST_ADDR1}^FS' from dual
 )
 select regexp_replace(t1.col, '({\w+.\w+})|.', '\1') res
  from t1
```

Result:

```
RES
-------------------------------------------
{CUSTOMERS.CUST_NAME}{CUSTOMERS.CUST_ADDR1}
```

Comment: Thanks -- this got me what I wanted (after adding a distinct clause and getting rid of the listagg and grouping).

Comment: I thought about replacing what doesn't match the pattern, but then I end up with tokens repeated many times across rows, and it's still difficult to sift through.  The first solution lets me get a distinct list of tokens used across all rows.

Answer (score 4):

I think there isn't. You should write some PL/SQL to get the others matching tokens. My best advice to you is to use a pipelined function.

First, create a type:

```
create type strings as table of varchar2(200);
```

Then the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function let_me_show
return strings PIPELINED as
   l_n number;
   l_r varchar2(200);
begin
   for r_rec in
      ( SELECT commands
        FROM MYTABLE )
   loop
      l_n := 1;
      l_r := REGEXP_SUBSTR(r_rec.COMMANDS,'\{\w+\.\w+\}', 1, l_n);
      while l_r is not null
      loop
         pipe row(l_r);
         l_n := l_n + 1;
         l_r := REGEXP_SUBSTR(r_rec.COMMANDS,'\{\w+\.\w+\}', 1, l_n);         
      end loop;       
   end loop;
end;
```

Now you can use the function to return the results:

```
select *
from table(let_me_show())
```